# Cannot assign value to string from Cloud Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

```
String stringEx;
documentRef = fs.document("Kullanıcılar/" + "Kullanici1");
documentRef .get().addOnSuccessListener(documentSnapshot -> {
    stringEx = documentSnapshot.getString("kullaniciAdi");
});
```

When I wrote this, stringEx has error.

Android Studio offers me to **convert stringEx to atomic** or **transform it to final one element array**.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: You can't assign to a local variable that belongs to an enclosing scope. You can only refer to a local variable if it is final or effectively final. The suggestions are to make it into some kind of container that you can put a string into, instead of assigning a variable.

Comment: I will use only a value so i wanted to assing to String.
Thank you much.

Comment: You may also find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value) useful. Even if you could set it there you wouldn't be able to use it immediately after that call.